# windows 11 firewall not opening ports

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-11, port-forwarding, web-services

I have this strange problem. I searched the forums for a week and everywhere i get the same suggestions i tried already or just not the same problem. If i missed one, please let me know.

I have installed 3 webservices on my windows 11 desktop pc. sabnzbd, sonarr, radarr.
I want to access them local using http://[ip]:[port].

the reason they are on windows is a long journey of struggles that at some point i just gave up and wanted to be done. they will move at some point in the future off my desktop pc but for now they are here and i deal with it.

The first sab worked almost out of the box. sonarr needed te restart in as admin once and i have a rule for nzbdrone and sonarr in the firewall to allow the port.

With all this up i wanted to do the same for radarr. so i set everything in de app settings the same as sonarr but a different port number. restarted the app as administrator and added the firewall rules. yet somehow radarr is just not showing up anywhere accept on the localhost.

What i have tried:

- switching my network from public to private;
- deleting the rules and setting it again;
- adding the rules with cmd using netsh advfirewall;
- turning the firewall off completely;
- setting other ports open;
- telnet from my laptop works for the sonarr port directly but no
  response from host on other ports;
- netstat -a -n -p tcp gives a list but radarr is not there;

Now this is about it for my knowledge on networking stuff. meaning i google stuff and hope it points me in the right direction.
So please if you have any suggestions, i would like to try but keep in mind this is not my aerie of expertise. It just really bugs me.

[Sonarr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onRvl.png)

[Radarr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMaF2.png)

[Firewall Odido (t-mobile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGED5.png)

[telnet/nc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEJk9.png)

I checked radarr log and it does appear to be listening:

```
2023-11-03 15:14:19.6|Info|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Now listening on: http://[::]:7878
```

Netstat results:

```
    TCP    0.0.0.0:7878           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:7878              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:7878             [::1]:50504            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:7878             [::1]:52609            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:7878             [::1]:53426            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:7878             [::1]:54236            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:7878             [::1]:55136            TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [::1]:7878             [::1]:55528            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:50504            [::1]:7878             ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52609            [::1]:7878             ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:53426            [::1]:7878             ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:54236            [::1]:7878             ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:55528            [::1]:7878             ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Did you try:  Windows Defender, Firewall, Advanced settings (on that page) which open the advance firewall settings (inbound and Outbound) .   Can you set firewall settings here?

Comment: Yes i tried that :( no change. It shows the rules, it just then ignores them and i'm at a loss to why. it almost feels like something is overruling it.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the definitions of the two firewall rules for sonarr and radarr. You may add screenshots to your post. Have you port-forwarded the ports on the router (if testing from outside the local network)?

Comment: I have added the screenshots to my post. I have logged on to my router but it is completely shut tight from my provider software. it has no options to change anything in there. stupid question maybe but does that matter for lan connections? the other didn't need any work in the router

Comment: I have added screenshots of the inbound rules and my zyxel firewall

Comment: The router probably doesn't matter inside the LAN. Try to disable the firewall completely, to see if it matters. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I disabled it from the interface with no result  and cmd also no result. It's a very persistent problem

Comment: The error is then probably in the Radarr application not listening on the port.

Comment: @harrymc maybe. then should i not be able to telnet to the [ip]:[port] from my laptop if it's open but there is nothing there? I will add a screenshot from my laptop.

Comment: the radarr log shows it listening on ipv6: `http://[::]:7878`, but is there another entry for ipv4 like `http://[0.0.0.0]:7878`? If it's only working on localhost, it could be binding to `127.0.0.1` instead. Check `netstat -an | findstr /c:7878` to see what all it's bound to

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I have added the info to my post, but you may be on to something because i believe ipv6 was turned off in my zyxel router.

Comment: That netstat binding looks correct. Your screenshot using `nc` shows you testing port `7979` though instead of `7878`. Is that the correct port, and is it also listening?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale good catch that is a stupid mistake on my part. 7979 is wrong. I tested 7878 and that gives back a succes instantly. so i guess that is good. but going to the page radar should be on still takes a long time and finally i get a message about how a secure connection could not be made to the server.

Comment: sounds like the firewall stuff is all set then. Is your browser attempting HTTPS when it should be doing HTTP? Normally only HTTP*S* tries a secure connection, and it would bind a separate port from HTTP which is listening on 7878

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I will check at that when I get home, but I'm a truck driver and I don't know if that will be before the weekend. I will reply as soon as I can.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thank you for your patience. Safari on my MacBook was trying to use https. I tried a different browser and made sure to use http:// but it will not work. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I bevlieve it should work by now...